# AngularJS - ForEach Accessing previous/next index array, Possible?

Tags: angularjs

```
  $scope.todos = [
    {text:'learn', done:true},
    {text:'build', done:false},
    {text:'watch', done:false},
    {text:'destroy', done:false},
    {text:'rebuild', done:false}];


  $scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo,i) {
      todo.text = 'want2learn';
      todo.text[i+1] = todo.text;
    });
```

is it possible for a ForEach function accessing/set previous/next index array value of object, Possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,

```
$scope.todos[i+1].text = todo.text;
```

You'll want to guard against indexing past the end of the array though:

```
if(i < $scope.todos.length - 1) {
   $scope.todos[i+1].text = todo.text;
}
```